# Find context free grammar and prove its correctness

Tags: context-free-grammar

> Find context free grammar for a given language and prove its correctness:
>
> a) $\left\{ a^ib^ja^k : i\neq j \ \vee \ j\neq k \right\}$
>
> b) $\left\{ w\in \left\{a,b\right\}^* : \#_a(w)=2 \cdot \#_b(w) \right\}$
>
> c) set of all words $w\in \left\{ a,b \right\}^*$ that have even length and numbers of occurrences of $b$ on even and odd positions are equal.

For a) and c) I have no idea. For b) I think I found it:
$$S\rightarrow SaSaSbS \ | \ SaSbSaS \ | \ SbSaSaS \ | \ \varepsilon$$
Seems correct, but don't know how to prove that every word that has twice many $a$'s than $b$'s can be produced by this grammar. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINTS:

(a) This is the union of the languages $\left\{a^ib^ja^k:i<j\right\}$, $\left\{a^ib^ja^k:i>j\right\}$, $\left\{a^ib^ja^k:j<k\right\}$, and $\left\{a^ib^ja^k:j>k\right\}$, and it’s not too hard to write context-free grammars for these languages.

(b) Finding a proof that your grammar generates the language $L=\{w\in\{a,b\}^*:|w|_a=|w|_b\}$ seems a bit difficult, but I can do it for a somewhat different grammar. Say that $w\in L$ is *irreducible* if it is non-empty and not of the form $uv$ for any non-empty $u,v\in L$. Prove that if $w$ is irreducible, then there is a $u\in L$ such that $w\in\{aaub,abua,buaa\}$. Then consider the grammar with these productions:

$$\begin{align*}
&S\to TS\mid\varepsilon\\
&T\to aaSb\mid abSa\mid bSaa
\end{align*}$$